# common-lisp loop の変数をbit型ではなく、Integerで回すには？

Tags: common-lisp

1から`入力1`までの整数の各桁の和が`入力2`以上`入力3`である数の合計を求めるプログラムを書いています。
そのために、関数`split-by-digit`を作りましたが実際に`loop`で1から`入力1`までの回数繰り返し処理を行おうとすると、`split-by-digit`の引数が`Bit`型で`Real`ではないと怒られます。
`loop`を整数で繰り返すまたは`Bit`型を`Integer`型にキャストするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

以下が実際に書いたプログラムになります。

```lisp
;; 数字列を分割
;; 数字列を分割
(defun split-by-space (string)
  (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
        as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
        collect (read-from-string (subseq string i j))
        while j))
;; 桁が２桁の場合１０の位と１の位を合計
(defun split-by-digit (number)
  (format t "~a~%" (type-of number))
  (if (< number 10)
      number
      (let* ((tenth (ceiling (floor number 10)))
         (oneth (mod number 10)))
    (+ tenth oneth))))
;; 入力を分割
(defparameter args (split-by-space (read-line *standard-input* nil nil)))
(defparameter maximum (car args))
(defparameter begin-from (cadr args))
(defparameter end-to (caddr args))
(defparameter summation 0)
;; maximum まで繰り返し
(loop for i real from 1 to maximum
      with val = 0
      do (setq val (split-by-digit i))
         (if (and (<= begin-from val)  (>= end-to val))
             (setq summation (+ summation i))))
(format t "~a~%" summation)
```

実行し、入力を与えると

```
Unhandled TYPE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                  {7005540003}>:
  The value
    NUMBER
  is not of type
    REAL
```

というエラーが出ます

Comment: split-by-digit 関数で `(if (< number 10) 'number ...` となっている部分ですが、`'number` は symbol になります。これはどの様な意図なのでしょうか? また、loop 部分の閉じ括弧が一つ多いです。

Comment: 括弧が一つ多いのは`format`を最後に持ってきたときのミスだと思います。 'numberはnumberに束縛されている値を返したいです

Comment: そうなりますと、そこは `number` でよいかと思います。また、また、`(and (>= begin-from val) (<= end-to val))` は逆で、`(and (<= begin-from val)  (>= end-to val))` だろうかと思います。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。修正、反映しておきます

Comment: SBCL 2.2.9 で掲示のコードを実行して、例えば `12 4 8` を入力すると `30` が返ります。これは想定通りの結果でしょうか？

Comment: はい。想定通りの結果です

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bit型をInteger型にキャストする

`bit` 型は `integer` 型でもあります。

[CLHS: Type BIT](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/t_bit.htm)

> Description:
>
> The type bit is equivalent to the type (integer 0 1) and (unsigned-byte 1).

```lisp
$ sbcl
This is SBCL 2.2.9.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.

* (type-of 0)
BIT
* (type-of 1)
BIT
* (type-of 2)
(INTEGER 0 4611686018427387903)
```

**余談**

`multiple-value-bind` を利用して以下の様に書くこともできます。(変数 `maximum`, `begin-from`, `end-to` はローカル変数になります)

```lisp
;; 数字列を分割
(defun split-by-space (string)
  (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
        as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
        collect (read-from-string (subseq string i j))
        while j))

;; 桁が2桁の場合10の位と1の位を合計
(defun split-by-digit (number)
  (format t "~d ~a~%" number (type-of number))
  (if (< number 10)
      number
      (+ (floor number 10) (mod number 10))))

;; 入力を分割
(defparameter summation 0)
(multiple-value-bind (maximum begin-from end-to)
    (values-list (split-by-space (read-line *standard-input* nil nil)))
  (loop for i to maximum
        for val = 0 then (split-by-digit i)
        if (and (<= begin-from val) (>= end-to val))
        do (incf summation i)))
(format t "~a~%" summation)
```